# Method for identifying arrays within a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of arrays that that has the following attribute:

```
>>> a.shape
(N, 7, 2)
```

Where `N` represents the number of sub-arrays within the array.

However, I need a method for identifying the sub-arrays for later use in my program. For example:

```
>>> a[13].id
13
```

Or something along those lines. I attempted subclassing the `ndarray` following [these](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) docs, but creating an array of them does not preserve any additional attributes added, such as :

```
>>> n = np.array([CustomArray(np.empty((7, 2)), id=i) for i in range(N)])
>>> n[0]
array([[0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
       [0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
       ...,
       [0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00]])
```

Where I had hoped for:

```
>>> n[0]
CustomArray([[0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
             [0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
             ...,
             [0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00]])
```

What I can think of is storing the pointers to the sub-arrays in a `dict` so that when needed I can "grab" the attributes from there, where the values would be a sub-`dict` (essentially JSON).

For example:

```
>>> hex(id(a[0]))
'0x1fcbd2e4c60'
>>> hex(id(a[1]))
'0x1fcbd341d00'
>>> shapes = {}
>>> shapes[a[0]] = {'id': None, 'record': None}
>>> shapes[a[1]] = {'id': None, 'record': None}
```

I thought that since clearly each `ndarray` of shape (7, 2) points to a different memory address, I could use that to later identify the associated `id` and `record`.

Suggestions?

Comment: They are not subarrays, numpy uses true multidimensional arrays, that is, there is a contiguous buffer allocated and the array object understands the strides / dimensions of your ndarray, it isn't an array that contains other arrays (so it can't be jagged for example)

Comment: But basically, your "subarrays" are *already identifiable with an index*, why would you need a dict? You could always use the index, maybe even in combination with a dict

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I thought about using the index, however the "subarrays" are going to be stored as values in a BST, in which the index inside the array will not translate during storage. For example, if the array is split at the BST root, then I cannot preserve indexing as there are now 2 arrays (left and right halves).

Comment: What? Again **there are no subarrays**. What exactly are you doing with a BST? Honestly, it sounds like `numpy.ndarray` simply isn't what you need. But you should elaborate more. You may have to do some additional arithmetic with the indexing, but you can probably use an index if you design your approach right. Again, need more details. Note, *Python doesn't have pointers* so you can't store pointers in a dict.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Preservation could potentially be implemented by passing along the indices during construction that represent the mapping to the original array.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga While it may not have a pointer type, I was thinking `shapes[a[0]] = {dict of attributes}`, since `a[0]` and `a[1]` represent "subarrays" and return different memory addresses of such. The values in this array represent the vertices of polygons. The BST is an implementation of a BVH, so the order in the array does not translate to the pre-order storage of the tree. So as you mentioned, some arithmetic would need to be do to keep track of which indices are currently being used when building down a branch.

Comment: Can you please give concrete examples? `shapes[a[0] = {dict of attributes}` doesn't make sense. Edit your question to add the additional details, don't want to use the comment section for this

Comment: Maybe a list of `N` arrays, each (7,2) shape, would fit your problem better.  Are you doing anything, other than indexing, along that first `N` dimension?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Unless  `hex(id(a[0]))` and `hex(id(a[1]))` have something else going on that don't actually reference unique `ndarray` objects of shape (7, 2)?

Comment: @hpaulj The Python list type exhausts memory for the use case. An `array.array` works well, but a `np.ndarray` gives me the best of both worlds.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Updated at end with an example of the `dict` storage.

Comment: @pstatix dude, **how many times do I have to repeat this** But there aren't any "subarrays". numpy.ndarray objects are essentially object-oriented views over a primitive buffer (array). `hex(id(a[0]))` is not giving you anything useful, so just ignore it. Again, Python doesn't have pointers. As an *implementation detail* that is giving you the address to the PyObject header, but again, that is not useful. Note, `a[0] is not a[0]`, but doing `a1 = a[0]; a2 = a[0]` will give you *two different array objects* each working with the same underlying buffer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "Pointers"/"References" whatever you want to call them, they are memory addresses under the hood that "point"/"refer" to where the object is stored and thus are unique. The better question is, why does `hex(id(a[0]))` not yield useful information? Why is that not saying "this memory address points to a block of memory showing this values"? The interpreter can return it, I've been able to access it it tests, so what are you saying it doesn't do?

Comment: Because the address of the PyObject header of the `numpy.ndarray` objedt isn't useful information to you. To put it succinctly, the block of memory it points to  (the PyObject header) isn't the block of memory you are interested in (the buffer)  What do you plan to do with that integer? You don't even seem to understand what it actually is. Again, note, `a[0] is not a[0]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But I just showed that they are different addresses...which is useful...they point to different groups of vertices. `a[0]` points to a different grouping than `a[1]`, so how is that not useful?

Comment: @pstatix **no it does not**. Do this: `arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]); a1 = arr[0]; a2 = arr[0]; a1[0]=99;` then `print(id(a1), id(a2))` then `print(a1, a2)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, your last comment was interesting. The address actually changes, which was not expected. So yes, the dictionary would not suffice. Begs another question, how does NumPy use an index to refer to a view over the array if the index has a changing address?

Comment: @pstatix dude, i've explained it multiple times, the **address is not the one you are interested in**. Stop thinking of it as an address, that is an implementaiton detail, it is the address of the PyObject header, and yes, it creates two different numpy objects that are *views over the same buffer*. again, a dictionary *could* suffice, depending on what you are tryin to do, but a dictionary to the values returned by `id` will not be useful to you in the slightest. Please re-read my comments carefully.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Until your second to last comment, I was unaware that slicing an `ndarray` produced a new id. Unlike a Python `list` where `l[0]` refers to the objects address in memory. The answer by @hpaulj wonderfully demonstrates this. Although the problem still exists with how to uniquely identify the "subarrays" (yes I am aware they are just view to homogeneous continuous memory) later within the program.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still having problems understanding your case, but may be this example will help illustrate how arrays are stored

Make a small 3d array:

```
In [197]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(4,3,2)
```

The array has a unique id:

```
In [198]: id(arr)                                                                                
Out[198]: 140699511092288
```

take 2 slices.  These are new arrays, with their own `id`, but they are views, and share memory with `arr`:

```
In [200]: a1 = arr[0]                                                                            
In [201]: a2 = arr[1]                                                                            
In [202]: id(a1)                                                                                 
Out[202]: 140699505822656
In [203]: id(a2)                                                                                 
Out[203]: 140699505820896
```

Slicing again produces a new array, with its own id, even though it is a view of the same part of `arr` as `arr1`:

```
In [204]: id(arr[0])                                                                             
Out[204]: 140699639227056
```

In other words, `arr[i]` is not a unique object; it's an array that's constructed new each time it is used.

I like to use `__array_interface__` to examine arrays and their slices:

```
In [209]: arr.__array_interface__                                                                
Out[209]: 
{'data': (67180512, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (4, 3, 2),
 'version': 3}
In [210]: a1.__array_interface__                                                                 
Out[210]: 
{'data': (67180512, False),           # same as for arr
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 2),
 'version': 3}
In [211]: a2.__array_interface__                                                                 
Out[211]: 
{'data': (67180560, False),           # 48 bytes further on (3*2*8)
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 2),
 'version': 3}
In [212]: arr[1].__array_interface__                                                             
Out[212]: 
{'data': (67180560, False),            # same as a2, but different id
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 2),
 'version': 3}
```

I could make a list of subarrays:

```
In [213]: alist = [arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3]]                                                  
In [214]: [id(i) for i in alist]                                                                 
Out[214]: [140699773687248, 140699814141824, 140699789628080, 140699639186176]
In [215]: id(alist[0])                                                                           
Out[215]: 140699773687248
```

As long as I'm referencing elements of that list, the ids are unique.

These 2 views have the same values, even though their ids are different:

```
In [216]: a1==alist[0]                                                                           
Out[216]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]])
```

Comment: I was unaware that using indexing/slicing with a NumPy array returned a view that shares memory with the stored values. First time extensively using NumPy and this differs drastically from a standard Python list where `l[0]` would return the address that refers to an object.

Comment: The size of the list of subarrays was problematic I am afraid, so I need to remain the `np.ndarray` space.

Comment: `l[0]` doesn't *return an address* for a Python list. It returns an object. The object at that index. `numpy.ndarray` objects do not generally hold objects (unless you use the object dtype, but let's ignore that for now). Every time you want to access data using indexing/slicing, it has to *box* the primitive data it is acting as a view over into a python object for it to be useful at the interpreter level

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is it not semantics to say address vs object? `o = l[0]` stores an address in `o` that was previously stored at index 0 of `l`. Feels silly to think or behave otherwise. The object exists only at the address, everything else refers to its location in memory. But I am now aware of how NumPy handles indexing/slicing and have saved [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) very useful link.